# Move files from sub folders to parent directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder structure that looks like this

```
|parent
|    |123
|    |    123abc.txt
|    |456
|    |    456def.txt
|    |789
|    |    789ghi.txt
```

and I want it to look like this

```
|parent
|    123abc.txt
|    456def.txt
|    789ghi.txt
```

There are over 2 million .txt files in this directory.

I followed [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/999922/move-all-files-from-multiple-subfolders-into-the-parent-folder) and the best answer was to run this

`FOR /R "Y:\Staging" %i IN (*.txt) DO MOVE "%i" "Y:\Staging2"`

I tried doing that, but all it did was move the folders that were in "Y:\Staging". It did not move any files in "Y:\Staging\Folder" where there are over 40k folders.

I need a way to recursively move files from each of the 40k folders *within* "Y:\Staging" and move them all to "Y:\Staging2"

Comment: You are not moving to a parent directory. You are just moving the file to a completely different directory.  If you were moving it to the parent directory it would get moved to  `Y:\Staging`.  Your code is moving it to `Y:\Staging2` which is not the parent directory of those files.

Comment: There's a very simple command you can use to provide a tree structure, `tree.com`. So instead of making things difficult for everybody, just use `tree.com /F /A Y:\Staging`, and you can copy the output from the third line `Y:\STAGING`, and paste it directly into your question.

Answer (score 0):

This would fail for any file with the same name, as it would attempt to use the same file name (sans path) when moving in to Y:\Staging2 folder.  I would look at ROBOCOPY:

```
ROBOCOPY  "Y:\Staging" "Y:\Staging2" *.txt /E /MOV
```